# Open cart not running when I transfer from server to localhost

Tags: php, opencart

I did the following to run an open cart site from the live server to localhost:

On both config.php I changed my files to the following:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://safetyelite.co.za/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://safetyelite.co.za/image/');
define('HTTP_ADMIN', 'http://safetyelite.co.za/admin/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://safetyelite.co.za/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http://safetyelite.co.za/image/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/system/logs/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite/catalog/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'safetyelite');
define('DB_PREFIX', '');
?>
```

I also went to my index.php and changed the directory under install to this:

```
// Install 
if (!defined('DIR_APPLICATION')) {
    header('Location: /http://localhost/safetyelite/install/index.php');
    exit;
}

// VirtualQMOD
require_once('/http://localhost/safetyelite/vqmod/vqmod.php');
```

When I load the page I get this error:

[image]

How can I load open cart on localhost?
I anything I could possibly be missing.

Please help

Comment: U have problem with vqmode files, try to disable them?

Comment: Do you mean a should remove the vqmode folder? sorry it's my first time on open cart so I may not understand things at first

Comment: `header('Location: /http://localhost/…` does not make any sense at all, and likely neither `require_once('/http://localhost/…` This gives the impression that you are changing values willy-nilly, without any actual idea what those values represent ...

Comment: Was meant to put the directory of the application so I did this: C:/xampp/htdocs/safetyelite

Answer (score 0):

require_once need the exact php file name as argument-

require_once('/http://localhost/safetyelite/vqmod/vqmod.php');

thus you have to change this line to -

require_once('./vqmod/vqmod.php');

Comment: I just made the change and after refreshing the page I received this error multiple times:

Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\safetyelite\vqmod\vqmod.php on line 247 and lastly this:
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\safetyelite\system\database\mysql.php on line 6

Comment: This means the previous issue is now fixed and it got stuck in vqmod.php  line 247. For now you can change the error reporting to hide deprecated message. error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

Comment: Not following what exactly I shall do? Is everything all right with the changes I made?@Cbroe said I did things the wrong way in the header(...)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give a propper path to require_once;

Change
`require_once('/http://localhost/safetyelite/vqmod/vqmod.php');`
 to
`require_once('vqmod/vqmod.php');`

Comment: I just made the change and after refreshing the page I received this error multiple times: Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\safetyelite\vqmod\vqmod.php on line 247 and lastly this: Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\safetyelite\system\database\mysql.php on line 6

Comment: Then you need to go thru those functions and update them.